# PHP preg_replace exclude &lt; and &gt;

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to change this code:

```
$output = preg_replace("#&lt;a ([^&gt;]*)&gt;([^&lt;]*)&lt;\/a&gt;#", "<a href=\"$1\">$2</a>", $output)
```

to make from `&lt;a some.url&gt;description&lt;/a&gt;` to HTML code `<a href="some.url">description</a>`, but after i changed `< and >` to `&lt; and &gt;` it doesn't make what I wanted.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

I wouldn't use `html_entity_decode()`, because I want this for enabling slightly simplified HTML tags, but the most of HTML i would have disabled.

Input for my function is a variable, obtained from a form:

Firstly the code replaces all `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Than it changes back some text-modifying static HTML tags, for example `<b>` and `</b>`.

But in the end, i want to change every link inputed as `<a some.url>link</a>` (and than by code changed to `&lt;a some.url&gt;link&lt;/a&gt;`) to be changed by `preg_replace()` into standard HTML code `<a href="some.url">link</a>`

Comment: Why don't you use [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)?

Comment: because i don't want to change **all** entities convert, but only in special occasions. I have done it for some other tags for example `<b>`, but they are static.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, but that's fine. If you could edit your question and add those "special occasions" with the desired output I may help you further.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

```
$str = "this 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;"
html_entity_decode($output)
// output This 'quote' is <b>bold</b>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

```
$str = "This 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";
htmlentities($output);
// output this 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
```

Comment: I can't use this because original is `<a link>` not `<a href=link>` & also I want to ban some (the most of) HTML tags in my function (that's why is `<` changed to `&lt;`).

But thank you for your help.